# Mysql query to find IDs from a list that don't exist in a table

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I'm trying to execute mysql query to find ids that dont exist in table but I'm getting an error. What am I doing wrong? Here is my query

```
create table scientist (id integer , firstname varchar(100), lastname varchar(100));
        insert into scientist (id, firstname, lastname) values (1, 'albert', 'einstein');
        insert into scientist (id, firstname, lastname) values (2, 'isaac', 'newton');
        insert into scientist (id, firstname, lastname) values (3, 'marie', 'curie');


select * from ( 
   VALUES ROW (1 , 2 , 3, 4, 5) 
)  as V
WHERE id not EXIST (select id from scientist);
```

I expect to see 4 and 5 in output

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You would use `not exists` like this:

```
select *
from (VALUES ROW (1) , ROW (2) , ROW (3), ROW (4), ROW (5)
     ) v(id)
where not exists (select 1 from scientist s where s.id = v.id);
```

Comment: select 1 or select id?

Comment: @Artem . . . It doesn't matter.  `exists` is checking whether or not a *row* is returned.  It doesn't care about the columns on that row.

Comment: ok, but why i cant use values like this VALUES ROW (1 , 2 , 3, 4, 5) ?

Comment: @Artem . . . That creates one row with five columns, which is not what you want.

Comment: What version of MySQL is this for? I get a syntax error near "values row(1)..." in MySQL 5.7.